# Pandas create a new column based on non-null value of another column

Tags: python, lambda

I have a dataframe where I want to create a new column based on an existing column where the values are non null.

The existing column is in decimals and some rows are null. I want to create a new column in integers.

I am using lambda but keep getting a syntax error. Could anyone tell me what's wrong? Thanks

```
df['new'] =  df['old'].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x>=0)
```

I also tried:

```
df['new'] =  df['old'].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x.isnull == False)
```

and this one:

```
df['new'] =  df['old'].apply(lambda x: x.astype(int) if x>=0)
```

The syntax error is pointing to the last close parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got syntax error, because your `lambda` function is not correct. Specifically, the `if ... else ...` [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) is wrong. The conditional expression must be

```
conditional_expression ::=  or_test [“if” or_test “else” expression]
```

You were missing `else` part.

Another thing I would like to mention is that the graceful way to convert the data type is to use [`astype` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html). If you want to cast data on some condition, you could do like:

```
new = df.loc[df.old>0].astype('int')
```

Then `new` would become a Series you need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['new'] =  df['old'].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x>=0)
```

You need to have an `else` at the end of the ternary operator.

```
df['new'] =  df['old'].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x>=0 else 'Nope')
```

Comment: Is there any way to use elif in lambda? For example, if I have three different values to apply based on three different conditions? Thanks.

Comment: You cant have statements in lambdas, so no, at least not in that form.  However you *can* chain the ternary operator: `val_1 if <exp_1> else <val_2> if <exp_2>....  `